# Matplotlib annotations: x coordinate constant and y dynamic

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

Suppose this is the code:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))

x = range(100)
y = range(100)
ax1.annotate((y[-1]), (x[-1], y[-1]),  bbox=dict(boxstyle='larrow', fc='0.8', ec='None'))
```

The arrow is too close to the graph, I would like it more to the right[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T9mN.png).
The proposed solution is to add a number to the x value. for example like this:

`ax1.annotate((y[-1]), (x[-1]+4, y[-1]),  bbox=dict(boxstyle='larrow', fc='0.8', ec='None'))`

The problem with that is that the graph is dynamic, and the value that needs to be added is proportional to the X value.

If there are 100 values in the X value, then you need to add 3 to move the arrow to the right, on the other hand, if there are 10,000 values in the X value, then you need to add 200, etc.

Is there a way to make the arrow stay in the same place for the x coordinate, and for the y coordinate will change according to the last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this: `textcoords=('offset points', 'data')` to the annotate parameters.

Like this:

```
ax1.annotate((x[-1]), (80, y[-1]), textcoords=('offset points', 'data'),  bbox=dict(boxstyle='larrow', fc='0.8', ec='None'))
```

Note that the value of the X coordination is a number which results from the position in the graph and not from the data, put any value you want.